# How to draw transparent text on form?

Tags: delphi, canvas, label

Is there a  way to draw a transparent text on form that has some controls?  If I use `TLabel` control, it would always show behind controls on the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use a `TLabel` control, since it is not a windowed control, and therefore it will be hidden by every windowed child control of the form. You could use a `TStaticText`, which is indeed a windowed control (a `STATIC` control), but it will be a bit difficult to make it truly transparent, I'd suppose.

You can use layered windows for this:

1. Create a new VCL project, and add a bunch of windowed controls to it.
2. Create a new form in the project, named `splash`. Set `BorderStyle` to `bsNone`, and set the font name, size, and colour to whatever you desire (e.g., Segoe UI, 42, red).
3. Add a public method

   ```
   procedure Tsplash.UpdateSplash(const Str: string);
   var
     R: TRect;
     P: TPoint;
     S: TPoint;
     bm: TBitmap;
     bf: TBlendFunction;
     EXSTYLE: DWORD;
     x, y: integer;
     pixel: PRGBQuad;
     TextRed,
     TextGreen,
     TextBlue: byte;
   begin
     EXSTYLE := GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
     SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, EXSTYLE or WS_EX_LAYERED);

     R := ClientRect;

     bm := TBitmap.Create;
     try
       bm.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
       bm.SetSize(ClientWidth, ClientHeight);

       bm.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
       bm.Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

       bm.Canvas.Font.Assign(Self.Font);
       bm.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
       DrawText(bm.Canvas.Handle, PChar(Str), Length(Str), R,
         DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_CENTER or DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS);

       TextRed := GetRValue(Font.Color);
       TextGreen := GetGValue(Font.Color);
       TextBlue := GetBValue(Font.Color);

       for y := 0 to bm.Height - 1 do
       begin
         pixel := bm.ScanLine[y];
         x := 0;
         while x < bm.Width do
         begin
           with pixel^ do
           begin
             rgbReserved := (rgbRed + rgbGreen + rgbBlue) div 3;

             rgbBlue := TextBlue * rgbReserved div 255;
             rgbGreen := TextGreen * rgbReserved div 255;
             rgbRed := TextRed * rgbReserved div 255;
           end;

           inc(pixel);
           inc(x);
         end;
       end;

       P := Point(0, 0);
       S := Point(bm.Width, bm.Height);
       bf.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
       bf.BlendFlags := 0;
       bf.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
       bf.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;
       UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, 0, nil, @S, bm.Canvas.Handle, @P, 0, @bf,
         ULW_ALPHA)
     finally
       bm.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```
4. To your main form, add private methods

   ```
   procedure TForm1.CreateSplash;
   var
     p: TPoint;
   begin
     splash.Visible := true;
     UpdateSplash;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.UpdateSplash;
   var
     p: TPoint;
   begin
     if not (Assigned(splash) and splash.Visible) then Exit;
     p := ClientToScreen(Point(0, 0));
     splash.SetBounds(p.X, p.Y, ClientWidth, ClientHeight);
     splash.UpdateSplash('Sample Text');
   end;
   ```

   and call `UpdateSplash` every time the form is moved or resized:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.WMMove(var Message: TWMMove);
   begin
     UpdateSplash;
   end;

   procedure TForm4.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     UpdateSplash;
   end;
   ```

Finally, you can do, just to try it out,

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if splash.Visible then
    splash.Hide
  else
    CreateSplash;
end;
```

[image: Sample screenshot]

[Compiled demo EXE](https://privat.rejbrand.se/layeralpha.exe)

Comment: A third party component: TcxLabel can achieve the same result too.