# How to turn form into a shape bitmap or gif?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

Is any Free Component/ Function like TAdvShaper (http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advshape.asp)?

Comment: This is easy to do manually. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14464315/282848), where the text 'Sample Text' actually *is* a form shaped like a bitmap.

Comment: That link is broken. Please describe the behavior you want.

Comment: @Rob: No link is broken...

Comment: It was broken when I visited it, @Andreas. Either way, a description independent of other products would make this a better question.

Comment: Rob is right. In addition, the sample image shown at TMS is very much *not* impressive, IMHO, due to the terrible lack of alpha transparency/anti-aliasing. It looks pretty horrible...

Comment: Look at [this tutorial](http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash/). In [the second part](http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash/2/) of it, you'll find the answer.

Comment: thank's sir,,, it look like my hope, i want to read first,,

Comment: I think it's a valid question, and I vote to re-open. specially since @TLama provided a very nice tutorial which can be posted as a valid answer (Although I'm pretty sure I've seen this question here before)